# Data.Text.ICU.Regex - How to get I16 value for find function?

Tags: regex, haskell

I'm trying to work with the `find` function from the [Data.Text.ICU.Regex](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu-0.6.3.7/docs/Data-Text-ICU-Regex.html) module, and I see that its second argument requires an `I16` datatype defined in the [Data.Text.Foreign](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Text-Foreign.html) module.

However, based on this module definition in Data.Text.Foreign

```
module Data.Text.Foreign
    (
    -- * Interoperability with native code
    -- $interop
      I16
```

it seems that the constructor for the `I16` newtype

```
-- | A type representing a number of UTF-16 code units.
newtype I16 = I16 Int
    deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Integral, Num, Ord, Read, Real, Show)
```

is not exported by the Data.Text.Foreign module.

How can I make use of the `find` function if I'm not able to construct a value of type `I16`?

Comment: There are many functions in the same module as `find` that have `I16` in their return type...

Comment: `I16` is also an instance of `Num` and `Integral`, so you can use it like any other numeric type.

Comment: ....so numeric literals such as 7 are valid as `I16` integers.

Comment: You can use, for example, 10 :: I16 to construct I16 type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @shachaf for illustrating the main idea that helped me figure it out.

`I16` is an instance of the `Num` and `Integral` typeclasses, so what I eventually did was use the `fromIntegral` function to "cast" an `Int` to `I16` like this:

```
fromIntegral 10
```

And in the other direction, converting an `I16` to `Int`:

```
fromIntegral someI16Value
```

which may require adding the `:: Int` type annotation, so it becomes:

```
fromIntegral someI16Value :: Int
```

@Yogesh Sajanikar is also right in that `10 :: I16` will work; I just tried it out on GHCI, but the above was what I eventually used in my code.